# How to open a deeplink without creating a new tab or window in a web extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an anchor tag which when selected should open a link to an external application (Obsidian). Here's an example link: obsidian://action?param1=value&param2=value.

I expect that clicking on the anchor opens the external application without creating windows or tabs.

##### Current Browsers:

- Firefox
- Chrome

##### Current Permissions:

- tabs
- storage

**I'm trying to avoid hosts_permissions if possible.**

##### Several tried methods:

In the below examples, my usage of the "browser" namespace is equivalent to the chrome namespace.

- selecting anchor href

  - this opens confirmation window inside popup which cuts off the confirmation since my popup is smaller in size
- window.open()

  - This opens a new tab which closes when the open button on the prompt window is selected. If the prompt is closed, an empty tab remains
- browser.scripting.executeScript

  - This requires the scripting permission which is fine, but opening a URL inside an injected script requires declared access to the tab URL (hosts_permissions in my case)
- window.open(message.value, '_self') within content_script

  - This works perfectly, except it requires the content_script and I need to match all URLs. Since I want to avoid hosts_permissions, this is not suitable
- browser.tabs.create()

  - Same behavior as window.open()

Maybe there is another way or something I didn't think of like being able to resize the prompt window?

Comment: You can try using protocol handlers. Another way is to use Native Messaging to open the application. You should be able to open the window directly with `window.open()` if Chrome recognizes the URL. Why are you trying to avoid `host_permissions`? I wouldn't use extension popups at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went ahead and tried to use protocol_handlers but couldn't seem to get it to work with my deeplink. I also noticed that they aren't supported in other browsers besides Firefox which is a bit of a bummer.

As for why I am avoiding host_permissions, I just don't think that they are needed. The rest of my extension works fine without them except this cosmetic flaw of opening an extra tab/window. It would be awesome to open the link without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I have found that `browser.tabs.update()` is perfect for my use-case! It calls the deep-link without opening a new tab or window and somehow avoids changing the tab URL. I assume the foreign protocol has something to do with this.

In my extension setup, I am calling this directly in the popup from an anchor tag.

Example:

```js
async function openDeeplink(deeplink) {
     const [activeTab] = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true});
     browser.tabs.update(activeTab.id, { url: deeplink });
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the entire code to `browser.tabs.update({ url: deeplink })` as the id is optional.

Comment: I missed that it was optional. Thanks, this is great!